# How to add a second database to the same connection (Apostrophe CMS Multisite)

Tags: apostrophe-cms

In the `construct` method of `apostrophe-pages/index.js`, thus far I have been using:

```js
self.apos.db.db = options.apos.db.db(process.env.THE_SECOND_DB);
```

However, it appears that with an update to multisite (or just the CMS), this is no longer possible with the same syntax.

Looking at `emulate-mongo-2-driver`, it looks like `newDb.db()` is expecting `client` to be defined for the following:

```js
return decorateDb(client.db(name));
```

However, `client` is undefined.

What is the best way to resolve this?

**EDIT** Looks like the issue was the change in dependency from `mongodb` to `emulate-mongo-2-driver`

So to resolve this I need to fork `multisite`. It would be nice to be able to configure whether we want to use the emulate driver for `multisite`, as I have no use for the v2 driver, and right now it's got my entire application down.

Comment: There's a PR in the works to help with this: https://github.com/apostrophecms/emulate-mongo-2-driver/pull/10

Comment: Also it is probably not a good idea to add a new "db" subproperty of "db" as that would overwrite the method you used to get a second db, if you ever wanted to use it again for another level.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved in a recent release of `emulate-mongo-2-driver`, so your original code will work with `npm update`. However it is not advisable to overwrite `apos.db.db` as you would need that to still be a method in the future if you wanted to get a reference to a third database. Instead create a new property with a meaningful name suited to your application.